# How can I use 'nx.draw()' together with 'nx.topological_sort()'

Tags: python, networkx

I have generated a directed balanced tree in my code and I want to visualize it using ***.draw()*** but incorporating the topological information. I thought there might be a way of using existing ***.topological_sort()*** together with it -through '***pos***' attribute maybe-, which I did not discover yet. Has anybody used them together?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a tree, you can use ['dot'](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation/dotguide.pdf) from [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) [via networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout.html#networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout) to generate the layout (i.e. the nodes' `pos`).

Dot will generate a hierarchical layout putting the root(s) of the tree at the top and branches and leafs at lower levels (or instead of a top-bottom, [produce a left-right layout](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:rankdir)).

Comment: I have followed your suggested way after I posed the questions. However this time I encountered problem about applying the **graphhiz** commands. For instance, I have applied write.dot as _nx.drawing.nx_agraph.write_dot(dot_filename)_ ; but I got following **ImportError: ('requires pygraphviz ', 'http://pygraphviz.github.io/')**. I still believe _graphiz_ is the package that I need, but there are a lot of problems to use it in my machine on my way.

Comment: If you are on a Debian based OS, please try `sudo apt-get install graphviz`, followed by `sudo pip install pygraphviz` OR `sudo apt-get install python-pygraphviz`. You don't have to save as `dot` first, you can `draw_graphviz` directly, please see https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_graphviz.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_graphviz or https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.pygraphviz_layout.html#networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.pygraphviz_layout